# Cloud Run Concurrency not working as expected

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, concurrency, google-cloud-run

I am currently benchmarking a Google cloud serverless container service: Cloud Run.

Based on [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy), I tried to implement a simple Golang web server:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}

func main() {
    log.Print("helloworld: starting server...")

    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "8080"
    }

    log.Printf("helloworld: listening on port %s", port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(fmt.Sprintf(":%s", port), nil))
}
```

I packaged it with this Dockerfile using `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/helloworld`:

```
FROM golang:alpine AS builder

#Set necessary environment variables needed for our image
ENV GO114MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64

# Move to working directory /build
WORKDIR /build

COPY main.go .

RUN go mod init main.go

# Build the application
RUN go build -o main .

# Build a small image
FROM alpine

COPY --from=builder /build/main /server
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates openssl


# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD ["/server"]
```

When I benchmarked my Cloud Run Service using [Bombardier](https://github.com/codesenberg/bombardier) 
`./bombardier -c 3 -d 500s -l -r 80 https://url.com`
The service scales to 5 cpu-s/s (5 containers) to handle 80 req/s on 3 connections. It seems strange because I did set the concurrency to 80 so I should only have 1 container (at most 2-3 for fault tolerance).

Based on this results, various connections and request per seconds parameters were tested and even an other language (Python). The ratio between requests and containers looks to remain between 10 and 15 req/s per container.

I benchmarked the golang server and the container locally, both were able to handle way more than 80 req/s.

Am I missing something here ? Or is it some Google hidden limitations ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't include "thanks" or similar in questions. See here: meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/… and here: meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it for more information.

Comment: Did you try to set a `--max-instances` parameter and to observe the difference?

Comment: By default `max-instances=1000`, I set `max-instances=1` with a req/s of 80 and i kept concurrency=80. The number of containers scaled to 7 which is a curious behavior. Moreover CPU is always at 2% utilization. The RAM is at 8% of 128MB

Comment: Other stats: 300 req/s -> 10 instances, CPU use 2,5%, 700 req/s -> 10 instances , CPU use 4,5%, 1100 req/s cloud run start to act weirdly and do not accept that much request.

Comment: Have you set `--concurrency` to a custom value? Please try including your deployment command in the question.

Comment: Off-topic but:  there's no such environment variable as GO114MODULE recognized by Go.

Comment: Tried with `gcloud run deploy test --platform managed --region europe-west1 --image gcr.io
/Project_id/image --concurrency 75`. Same scaling: 4 containers for 65 req/s

Comment: flomalb@, did it work like that?

Comment: @asbovelw, The bug was reported to google cloud run product team, a fix has been deployed since

Comment: @flomalb I'm having the same issue (have set "maximum concurrent requests per instance" to 80 (the default). Minimum instance is set to 0, but it will quickly go to 2 or 3 instances under the lightest of loads (e.g a 99% of 2 concurrent requests!). Did you get a resolution from GCP?